# Disable auto language switch in Aptana

Tags: php, ide, aptana

I use Aptana as PHP IDE,
my source code is multilingual and when I'm in a string which is Arabic or Persian the keyboard layout will switch to Arabic or Persian, and when I'm in English string the keyboard layout will switch to English automatically,

How can I disable this feature in Aptana ?

Comment: Are you sure this is only Aptana and not your OS?

Comment: Yes, I have this problem only in Aptana, I work with DreamWeaver too but I don't have this problem, I think this is Aptana Feature

Comment: Well, I couldn't find any other mentions of it. You might see if broadening your search to include Eclipse helps, as the majority of Aptana is just Eclipse. I doubt they made special language handling just for Aptana since its main purpose is just to focus on Ruby/Python/Web development. Good luck.